# Проблемы с кодировкой в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

В php `echo` выдает вопросительные знаки. Делаю обращение к базе с кодировкой `utf8_general_ci`.

Код:

```
$eventorg_1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `topfive` WHERE  `id` = '1'");
$topfive_1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eventorg_1);
$topfive_11 = $topfive_1['anun'];
echo $topfive_11;
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Кодировка самой страницы нормальная?

Comment: да установлено правильно <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">

Comment: Посмотрите что вообще в базе написано. Может там уже знаки вопроса и записаны. Подключитесь через phpMyAdmin или из командной строки (только там тоже обязательно нужную кодировку укажите)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SET NAMES utf8`, который используется в многих фреймворках и CMS не является правильным, хотя когда речь идет о кодировках *latin1* и *utf8* это не принципиально. Правильный путь такой:

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

или, если вы вдруг используйте устаревший mysql:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

По сути эти методы аналогичны установке кодировки клиента через `SET NAMES`, но также сохраняют эту кодировку на стороне клиента, что учитывается в функциях экранирования.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не помогает, я поставил это в таким образом mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8"); все база данный установлено utf8_general_ci не и .htaccess написано вот такой код AddDefaultCharset utf-8 не помогает, что еще можно делать?

Answer (score -1):

Перед началом запросов выполнить:

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```